# I've been rejected during the application process, and I want to ask some more details on why. Is this okay?

Tags: hiring-process, applications

I've been through a quite long application process, and in the end I've been rejected. I've been sent an e-mail where they explicitly recognized the "strength" of my profile, but they decided to not proceed further.

Because during the application I did a couple of coding tests and several phone interviews, and they also led me to understand that I was a good match for the position I was applying for, I would like to know what specifically was my weakness.

Is it okay if I ask? Or do you think it's inappropriate?

Comment: You can ask, but don't expect an answer. There's no benefit to the hiring company and only opens them up to potential risks.

Comment: What kind of risks could the company go through? I don't see really the problem.

Comment: @user8469759 they can say stuff you can sue them for.  Best for them to say nothing at all.

Comment: I see. Ok then, but I just wanted to know what should I improve for my future applications.

Comment: Catering to your needs is not a priority of theirs.

Comment: Yes it is inappropriate.

Comment: @HLGEM, why? I don't think I would offend anybody.

Comment: Because there is close to a zero chance anyone will tell you and asking makes you look as if you are unrealistic and childish. If that is the impression you want them to have, go ahead and waste their time. They won't appreciate it. It will move you further down in the their minds as someone to hire at some future date in case this was a close decision, but go ahead and behave like a child.

Comment: Their hiring process is done and right now, it's better them and they're happy that it's behind them. You're wasting their time by wanting them to go over it with you again. The universe is not about you, you, you and your needs.

Comment: @HLGEM I don't think asking in general could classify me as child... but I do understand that the odds of getting a reply are close to 0.

Comment: You are already coming across as naive here. "they explicitly recognized the strength of my profile" That is plain sugarcoating or "softening the blow" and means nothing. Nobody will write a rejection mail saying, "ha ha, you suck, we don't like you". Instead they will write, "your credentials are impressive, but we decided to not proceed further at this point" or something like that. Don't take it at face value and ask, "Oh yeah? What was wrong?" Multiple people have told you here not to do it, and you responding with "Oh no, I don't think that's a problem" does make you sound childish.

Comment: Even if it *is* inappropriate to ask, the worst that will happen is that they don't answer and then decide not to hire you (but they already decided not to).

Comment: @MaskedMan out of interest, why do you think 'okay' is an improvement on 'OK'?

Comment: Most of these comment are wrong, i have in the past received valuable and honest feedback on why i was rejected. Not from HR though, but from the person that would have been my colleague had i gotten the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it ok if I ask?

It's always okay to ask. If you do, it makes sense to ask about your perceived strengths and weaknesses.

But very few would bother to give you feedback - there's nothing for them to gain by providing it. I know I wouldn't.

And if you are thinking you can get them to change their mind about your rejection or want to argue, don't waste your time. No hiring manager, HR rep, or recruiter I know would ever go along with that.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few possibilities:

1. In the end, they didn't think you had some of the required skills or personal attributes. If this is the situation, then they may well be able to give you some advice on how to improve your skills to be a better match for such a position.
2. They did think you had the required skills and attributes, but they had another candidate who was even stronger. If this is the situation, there may be nothing useful they can say, as it would be unethical for them to discuss someone else's strengths with you.
3. Something strange went on, like they decided not to create this particular position after all, or they rejected you for an 'unethical' reason. If this is the case, clearly they won't want to say anything to you.

So there is absolutely no harm in asking for feedback on how you could improve the package you are offering, but as people have said in the comments, there are a number of reasons why they may not be able or willing to say much.