# Applied for a job a couple of months ago. No reply. Should I reach the Executive Director?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, ethics, applications

I've applied a couple of months ago to a very interesting position in a blue chip company (North America). I think I'm qualified for this position (my skills match the position's skills list) but unfortunately the company never replies.

I really want to work in that (famous) company. Thankfully I'm connected on LinkedIn with their Executive Director (but I don't know him personally).

Is it a bold move to send him a (nice) message directly? Like 'What could I do to increase my chances to be considered for that particular position'. Or I might be black listed?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related post about asking that question during the interview stage: [Can I ask "Is there anything that I can do to increase my chance of getting the job?"?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/112449) (but I wouldn't recommend asking the question in the top-voted answer before you've even spoken to anyone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly I think you need to prepare yourself for the fact that you probably just didn't get the job - while recruitment processes can drag out (especially at large companies) hearing *nothing* for months after an initial application is usually an implied rejection. Yes it's a bit rubbish that they don't send even boilerplate rejections but it's still hugely common.

That said there's no real harm to be done by following up as to whether the position (or a similar one) is still open. Unless the position you applied for is at a very senior level however I don't think messaging the Executive Director is the right approach though. Chances are he won't even know about the position let alone that you applied or what happened to your application.

Your proposed message would be like sending the President of the US an e-mail asking why your local city councilor hasn't gotten back to your e-mail about street lighting from 6 months ago. They just aren't the right person to ask as that information simply isn't in their orbit.

A better approach would be to reach out to HR or to whomever you directed your original application to and politely inquire with them. Doing this is unlikely to cause any harm to any future chances there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much appreciated! I like the US President comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Your first move should be to contact HR at the company.  Email them and ask if the position is still available, or another like it.

As for contacting the Executive Director, that's a long shot.  You say this company is famous, so I assume it's large.  Many high level executives at companies do not manage their LinkedIn profiles, but have others do it for them.  They get flooded with connection requests and InMail and do not want to be bothered by it.  It is entirely possible to contact him or her, but the likelihood is low.  It is possible his or her assistant may pass it along, but again, the likelihood is low.  It is entirely possible that the ED would be annoyed by a request, as I have heard this does happen.  Personally, I don't think it would hurt, but don't have high expectations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, very useful. Indeed his LinkedIn page seems to relay only "official" information about the company.